# Reload/Reconstruct WooCommerce Payment Gateway on payment field change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find an elegant way to get a plugin/WooCommerce payment gateway to reload when a checkout field is updated (billing postcode).

Specifically for the Stripe Payment plugin. When it is initially constructed it creates the Stripe JS object and passes it a couple of parameters. I am changing the publishable key parameter based on the billing post code given.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_params', [$this, 'params_publishable_key_handle']);
public function params_publishable_key_handle($params)
{
  $params['key'] = $this->publishable_key;
  return $params;
}
```

For context Stripe does this through a method (`payment_scripts`) which runs `stripe.js` while passing it the params. `payment_scripts` is fired through `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

When the billing postcode field is changed WooCommerce performs a totals update, and the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` action is run. But this does not perform a full refresh of plugins, and so the Stripe plugin is not constructed again with my new set of keys (due to billing postcode being changed).

I attempted to force the plugins to reload with:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'test_reload_function', 99999);
function test_reload_function() 
{
    do_action( 'muplugins_loaded' );
}
```

But this doesn't trigger the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and so Stripe's `payment_scripts` is not called again.

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to force the Stripe plugin to reload. Or otherwise, how I can refresh the checkout browser page when the billing postcode is edited.

Edit: I think there might be a nice way to do this by editing the `assets/js/frontend/checkout.js` script (using the `script_loader_tag` filter), and change the `update_checkout_action` method to always reload the page if billing post code was updated. Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Does fields datas is being saved between reloads ? If you press F5 while in a cart, is the data updated ?

Comment: @amarinediary Yes. The billing postcode is saved against on the user's metadata (`customer->get_billing_postcode();`).